# bird's eye view opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get Bird's eye view of an image that I took with my camera, so that only the white lanes are shown. The resolution is 640x480. Here is the image - [image: image from camera]
What I do is first apply histogram equalizer and binary threshold,then define the 4 coordinates that I will use in getPerspectiveTransform and the result coordinates.

```
    int bottom_leftx = 110;
    int bottom_lefty = 480;

    int upper_leftx = 260;
    int upper_lefty = 120;

    int upper_rightx = 410;
    int upper_righty = 120;

    int bottom_rightx = 560;
    int bottom_righty = 480;


    Point2f src_vertices[4];
    src_vertices[0] = Point(bottom_leftx, bottom_lefty);
    src_vertices[1] = Point(upper_leftx, upper_lefty);
    src_vertices[2] = Point(upper_righty, upper_righty);
    src_vertices[3] = Point(bottom_rightx, bottom_righty);


    Point2f dst_vertices[4];
    dst_vertices[0] = Point(0, 480);
    dst_vertices[1] = Point(0, 0);
    dst_vertices[2] = Point(640, 0);
    dst_vertices[3] = Point(640, 480);
```

Then apply warpPerspective -

```
void getBirdView(Point2f *p1, Point2f *p2, const Mat& src, Mat& dst) {
    Mat warpMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform(p1, p2);

    warpPerspective(src, dst, warpMatrix, dst.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);
}
```

And instead of getting only the two parallel lines, I am getting that - 
[image]

So how did that white color come to my result? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my result:

[image]

---

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;

void transform(Point2f* src_vertices, Point2f* dst_vertices, Mat& src, Mat &dst){
    Mat M = getPerspectiveTransform(src_vertices, dst_vertices);
    warpPerspective(src, dst, M, dst.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);
}

int main(){
    Mat src = imread("test.png");

    Point2f src_vertices[4];
    src_vertices[0] = Point(270,120);
    src_vertices[1] = Point(395, 120);
    src_vertices[2] = Point(560, 480);
    src_vertices[3] = Point(110, 480);

    Point2f dst_vertices[4];
    dst_vertices[0] = Point(0, 0);
    dst_vertices[1] = Point(640, 0);
    dst_vertices[2] = Point(640, 480);
    dst_vertices[3] = Point(0, 480);

    Mat M = getPerspectiveTransform(src_vertices, dst_vertices);
    Mat dst(480, 640, CV_8UC3);
    warpPerspective(src, dst, M, dst.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT);

    Mat dst2(480, 640, CV_8UC3);
    transform(src_vertices, dst_vertices, src, dst2);


    imshow("src", src);
    imshow("dst", dst);
    imshow("dst2", dst2);
    waitKey();
}
```

Comment: Hm, if I do it that way -                                                                         
          `void getBirdView(Point2f *p1, Point2f *p2, Mat& src, Mat& dst) {
 Mat warpMatrix = getPerspectiveTransform(p1, p2);
 
 warpPerspective(src, dst, warpMatrix, dst.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT); } 
              Mat rotated;
   
  getBirdView(src_vertices, dst_vertices, dst, rotated);
  `    doesn't work